# How Can I Keep Rows of a Pandas Dataframe where two entries are within a week of each other?

Tags: pandas, jupyter, data-science

My data looks like this the following. I have a groupby to group the Visit_id's but now I want to delete all rows unless that Visit_id has two Visit_time's that are within a week of each other.

```
df allVisits:

Visit_id    Visit_time
162         2009-01-21 00:00:00.000
162         2012-09-05 00:00:00.000
213         2010-06-21 00:00:00.000
213         2010-06-22 00:00:00.000 
216         2011-07-06 00:00:00.000
216         2012-04-11 00:00:00.000
216         2012-04-12 00:00:00.000
```

I want it to look like:

```
Visit_id    Visit_time
213         2010-06-21 00:00:00.000
213         2010-06-22 00:00:00.000 
216         2012-04-11 00:00:00.000
216         2012-04-12 00:00:00.000
```

Currently the code I have is:

```
allVisits.groupby(['Visit_id']).apply()
```

What can I do from here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to include the third record for `Visit_id == 216`? Or do you only want to keep records that are within 7 days of another record within that `Visit_id`?

Comment: Based on your description, shouldn't record '216         2011-07-06 00:00:00.000' be kept as well?

Comment: @3novak only keep records less than or equal to a week apart within that Visit-id

Answer (score 1):

**Interpretation 1**

If you mean to keep all records with a `Visit_id` that has at least two records within a week of each other, this is one way to do that.

```
df.sort_values(['Visit_id', 'Visit_time'], inplace=True)  # sort the rows by date

# shift the records within each group to find the time difference
# between the dates of the records
df['time_shift'] = df.groupby('Visit_id')['Visit_time'].transform(lambda x: x.shift())
df['time_diff'] = (df['time_shift'] - df['Visit_time']).dt.days

# filter the dataframe on the Visit_ids that have dates within 7 days of each other
df.groupby('Visit_id').filter(lambda x: (abs(x['time_diff']) <= 7).any())

#    Visit_id Visit_time  time_shift  time_diff
# 2       213 2010-06-21         NaT        NaN
# 3       213 2010-06-22  2010-06-21       -1.0
# 4       216 2011-07-06         NaT        NaN
# 5       216 2012-04-11  2011-07-06     -280.0
# 6       216 2012-04-12  2012-04-11       -1.0
```

**Interpretation 2**

If you mean to only keep records that are within 7 days of each other, try the following solution.

```
df.sort_values(['Visit_id', 'Visit_time'], inplace=True)  # sort the rows by date

# shift the records within each group to find the time difference
# between the dates of the records
df['time_shift'] = df.groupby('Visit_id')['Visit_time'].transform(lambda x: x.shift())
df['time_diff'] = (df['time_shift'] - df['Visit_time']).dt.days

df['keep_idx'] = df.groupby('Visit_id')['time_diff'].transform(lambda x: abs(x) <= 7)
# we need to undo the shift we performed before and make sure that
# we capture both records involved. Hence the OR operation.
df['keep_idx'] = df['keep_idx'] | \
     df.groupby('Visit_id')['keep_idx'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1)
df.loc[df['keep_idx'] > 0]  # subset on the indices we want

#    Visit_id Visit_time  time_shift  time_diff
# 2       213 2010-06-21         NaT        NaN
# 3       213 2010-06-22  2010-06-21       -1.0
# 5       216 2012-04-11  2011-07-06     -280.0
# 6       216 2012-04-12  2012-04-11       -1.0
```

You could turn either of these into a function and use the `apply` method if you'd like, but the solutions above are given line by line for clarity.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @3novak, I'm getting an error on your third code line, it says subtraction isn't supported for types float and string

Comment: Hmmm, that's bizarre since the `time_shift` column should be the same type as `Visit_time`. Call `dtype` on each column to figure out which one is a string and cast as numeric. That hopefully resolves the issue.